# How to know the return result if I call a method from another contact

Tags: solidity

In solidity, how do I know the **return** result if I **call** from another contract?
From contract B, call contract A's method methodA,
if contract B, can I write:

```
Contract B{
     bool callResult=contractA.methodA(param);
}
```

or something similiar to this in solidity, any example?

Comment: If contractA.methodsA returns a boolean value, then yes.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little gist.

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract A {

    function methodA(string param) public pure returns(string) {
        // ignoring param but leaving it in the pattern to show how it would fit
        return "Behold";
    }

}

contract B {

    A contractA;

    constructor() public {
        contractA = new A();
    }

    function callA(string param) public view returns(string) {
        string memory callResult=contractA.methodA(param);
        return callResult;
    }

}
```

To see it work in Remix,

1. deploy B then
2. call B.callA("anything").

`contractA` is cast as type `contract A` and then instantiated by the constructor that just creates a new one and keeps an eye on where it is. This sidesteps some real use-case deployment concerns.

Another non-obvious aspect of this is that when B is compiled, the compiler can "see" the code for A. This familiarizes B with the interface to A.

Hope it helps.

Comment: in my case it is different, the contract A has been deployed already so if I deploy B right now, it will say the declaration A contractA; is wrong, since the contract does not know A. I use remix to compile B only

Comment: I also try resultCall=contractAdd.call(bytes4(sha3("removeToken(address, uint256)")),contractAdd,amount);, but it looks like the return is error, not string? or bool?

Comment: That's a separate issue. Deployment. You need to add a function or a constructor argument to tell it where the deployed contract is.

Comment: any example? Thanks, or I need something like interface?